# Why do different metal ions release different colors of light?

Tags: spectroscopy

For example, potassium chloride released a purple colored flame? 
Does it have to do with the energy level of the valence electrons in the metal cation that is being burned?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it depends on the energy level of valance electrons, but more precisely it depends on the difference between the highest occupied and lowest unoccupied levels' energies. If the energy difference is $\Delta E$ then the light emitted by the excited atom has a frequency $\nu = \frac{\Delta E}{h}$ so a wavelength $\lambda = \frac{c}{\nu}=\frac{h c}{\Delta E}$

Comment: How does this relate to the energy level of valence electrons? Lithium's valence electron energy level is 2, and it creates a red pinkish color. Barium , with a valence electron energy level of 6, creates a light green flame color. Potassium on the other hand, with a valence electron energy level of 4, burns a purple color, meaning that it has a high frequency. So is there even a relation between the valence electron energy level and the frequency of the wavelengths of the flames?

Comment: The energy level can be expressed in two different ways; the one, you are using is denoting the principal quantum number $n$ that only enumerates the energy levels but it doesn't say anything (directly) about their energy-value measured in Js or in eVs. When you solve the Schrődinger equation for an atom or ion you get the possible energies (eigenvalues) of your system and these are quantized so you can denote them with whole numbers ($n$, $l$, $m$ and $s$). However these are only serial numbers, not energies, so their difference is meaningless in this context.